# How do I choose an item in my list with an input command?

Tags: python, list, input

So Im trying to make an easy candybag. With one option to choose candy in the bag and one option to randomize the bag.
The random bag works, but how do I choose specific candy from the list, using an input from the user?

This is how i wrote that part.

```
os.system("cls")
customer_bag = []
candy_types = [["Sour strings", 2], ["Red Racecars", 2], ["Raspberry Boats", 1], ["Banana Skids", 3], ["Jungle Roar", 1], ["The Oh no Candy", 0,5]]
candy_types.sort()
for types in candy_types:
    print(types)

print("\nDo you want to choose candy or buy the shuffled candybag?")
candy_bag = int(input("1. Choose Candy\n2. Shuffle!!!"))

if candy_bag == 1:
    os.system("cls")

    candy_choice = candy_bag[]
    input()
    

elif candy_bag == 2:
    os.system("cls")

    print(random.choice(candy_types))
    print(random.choice(candy_types))
    print(random.choice(candy_types))
    print(" ")
    input("Press enter to return to Menu!")'''
```

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of list of lists!

Answer (score 0):

Add number of item while printing. And then just do another input() with number of item.

```
import os

os.system("cls")
customer_bag = []
candy_types = [["Sour strings", 2], ["Red Racecars", 2], ["Raspberry Boats", 1], ["Banana Skids", 3], ["Jungle Roar", 1], ["The Oh no Candy", 0,5]]
candy_types.sort()
for i, types in enumerate(candy_types, start=1):
    print(i, types)

print("\nDo you want to choose candy or buy the shuffled candybag?")
candy_bag = int(input("1. Choose Candy\n2. Shuffle!!!").strip())

if candy_bag == 1:
    os.system("cls")

    candy_choice = int(input("1. Choose Candy:"))
    candy_bag = candy_types[candy_choice - 1][0]
    print(candy_bag)


elif candy_bag == 2:
    os.system("cls")

    print(random.choice(candy_types))
    print(random.choice(candy_types))
    print(random.choice(candy_types))
    print(" ")
    input("Press enter to return to Menu!")
```

Comment: Seems like that works, thank you!! But If i wanted 3 choices from the candy - how do I proceed? Im very new to this and trying to get my head around things! :)
Thanks!

Comment: @Fenriz: Put code that I added to a loop and gather responses to a list. Then in another loop print result.

Comment: Not quite sure where to set the loop. When I try putting it into a loop it says "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"...

Trying to figure out the right way to loop it.